# image display from servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I need to display image from servlet to my android application how can i do it please some one help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following steps:

1. Use AsyncTask to download image from the servlet asynchronously, save it to file (either  in memory or on memory card)
2. In activity, place ImageView where you want image to be shown.
3. Convert loaded image to bitmap:

---

```
FileInputStream fis;
Bitmap image;
try {
fis = new FileInputStream("path to downloaded image");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// handle exception
}
```

4. Set bitmap to ImageView.